# SQL Time Series Completion Script

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2014

**Version:** SQL Server 2014

**Objective:** Create a complete time series with existing date range records.

**Initial Data Setup:**

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#DataSet') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #DataSet;

CREATE TABLE #DataSet (
    RowID INT
    ,StartDt DATETIME
    ,EndDt DATETIME
    ,Col1 FLOAT);

INSERT INTO #DataSet (
    RowID
    ,StartDt
    ,EndDt
    ,Col1)
VALUES
    (1234,'1/1/2016','12/31/2999',100)
    ,(1234,'7/23/2016','7/27/2016',90)
    ,(1234,'7/26/2016','7/31/2016',80)
    ,(1234,'10/1/2016','12/31/2999',75);
```

**Desired Results:**

```
RowID, StartDt, EndDt, Col1
1234, '01/01/2016', '07/22/2016', 100
1234, '07/23/2016', '07/26/2016', 90
1234, '07/26/2016', '07/31/2016', 80
1234, '08/01/2016', '09/30/2016', 100
1234, '10/01/2016', '12/31/2999', 75
```

Not an easy task I will admit, If anyone has a suggestion on how to tackle this utilizing SQL alone (Microsoft 2014 TSQL) I would greatly appreciate it.  Please keep in mind it is SQL and we want to try to avoid cursors at all costs based on performance for large data sets.

Thanks in Advance.

Also as an FYI I was able to achieve half of this by utilizing a LEAD windows function to set the End Date of the current record to the Startdate-1 of the next. The other half of filling gaps back in from previous records still eludes me.

Updated for the 9/31 to 9/30 date.

Comment: So if there are 2 intervals covering to the same day, which one takes priority? For example: `7/26/2016`, the second row says 90, but third row says 80.

Answer (score 0):

The following query does essentially what you are asking. You can tweak it to fit your requirements. Note that when checking the results of my query, your desired results contain 09/31/2016 which is not a valid date.

```
    WITH
    RankedData AS
    (
      SELECT RowID, StartDt, EndDt, Col1,
        DATEADD(day, -1, StartDt) AS PrevEndDt,
        RANK() OVER(ORDER BY StartDt, EndDt, RowID) AS rank_no
      FROM #DataSet
    ),
    HasGapsData AS
    (
      SELECT a.RowID, a.StartDt,
        CASE WHEN b.PrevEndDt <= a.EndDt THEN b.PrevEndDt ELSE a.EndDt END AS EndDt,
        a.Col1, a.rank_no
      FROM RankedData a
        LEFT JOIN RankedData b ON a.rank_no = b.rank_no - 1
    )
    SELECT RowID, StartDt, EndDt, Col1
    FROM HasGapsData
    UNION ALL
    SELECT a.RowID,
      DATEADD(day, 1, a.EndDt) AS StartDt,
      DATEADD(day, -1, b.StartDt) AS EndDt,
      a.Col1
    FROM HasGapsData a
      INNER JOIN HasGapsData b ON a.rank_no = b.rank_no - 1
    WHERE DATEDIFF(day, a.EndDt, b.StartDt) > 1
    ORDER BY StartDt, EndDt;
```

Comment: This is very close to what I am wanting, I will try to make it work and get the Col1 value correct. Currently that "Gap" record that needs inserted back in needs to be that 100 value that overlaps from the first record.  Sorry if that part wasn't implied well enough on my part.